# How to bridge Parallels network to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, parallels-desktop, internet-sharing

I've got a MacBook Pro, and I've got an IIS server in Windows, running in my Parallels Desktop for Mac. I need to connect to the server running on my virtual Windows from my iPhone.

In my home network I can bridge the WiFi to Parallels, connect both Windows and my iPhone to my home wifi, they are all in the same subnet and I can connect perfectly.

However, when I'm outside, I need a mechanism to connect my iPhone to my VM running inside Parallels. My VM has an 10.x.x.x IP and can communicate with my Mac (and the Internet, over my Mac's shared inner connection). My iPhone is connected over USB (I can switch to Bluetooth or WiFi too) as the hotspot to Internet, and has 172.20.x.x IP. Parallels VM and my iPhone are normally in completely separate subnets, but they are both connected to my Mac. Is there a way to bridge these connections to allow traffic from my iPhone to Parallels?